How to handle Compound Text Encoding in X11 library?
I am getting window title in Xlib using "WM_NAME" window property, and I have discovered that there is different string types that the property returns. For string type there is "UTF8_STRING" atom, XA_STRING (ISO-8859-1), and also some "COMPOUND_TEXT" atom. While "UTF8_STRING" and XA_STRING seems straightforward to use, I have found "COMPOUND_TEXT" a bit complicated to use.
Here is the only information I found online: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7-RC1/doc/xorg-docs/ctext/ctext.html
The end goal is to parse compound text or at least convert it to a valid UTF-8 string.

For the current workaround to get valid UTF-8 text I am using example from xdotool: https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/f61ed0e32123c73c0e429f6adecc421fe4383e00/xdo.c#L1907
But if "_NET_WM_NAME" fails then "WM_NAME" would be populated and there the issue comes that there is no handling for non-UTF-8 characters.

You can totally ignore compound text window names.
“Compound Text Encoding” provides a way to use multiple character sets (similar to what Windows would call “code pages”) for international text: European languages with diacriticals, Cyrillic languages, Hebrew, Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc.
All modern window managers use UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters.
The document you linked is pretty straight-forward, but like all X-Consortium standards, is written in a fairly opaque way. It gives all the necessary definitions right at the top, though, so if you take your time you can get through it just fine.
But again, unless you are supporting arbitrary antique *nixen on X11, you can totally ignore it and get along just fine.

You can get wm name by XGetTextProperty, and then get encoding. Do it like that:
char *get_wm_name(Window win, Atom atom)
{
    int n;
    char **list=NULL, *result=NULL;
    XTextProperty name;

    if(!XGetTextProperty(display, win, &name, atom))
        return NULL;

    if(name.encoding == XA_STRING)
        //((char *)name.value) is wm name;
    else if(name.encoding == UTF8_STRING))
        Xutf8TextPropertyToTextList(xinfo.display, &name, &list, &n);
        //(*list) is wm name
    else // use iconv() or other API to get wm name
    ...
}

